# xp repair installation halted by Safety Center malware

Tags: virus-removal, malware-removal

Due to an oversaturation of malware on the machine, I've been trying to reinstall windows xp professional over the old installation only to be halted by a safety center malware screen.  Most of the removal tutorials suggest to go through add/remove programs.  Of course i'm unable to do this because I'm in the middle of a reinstallation.

Does any one know how to about doing this through perhaps ASR?  I have also tried going through ASR except I receive an "access denied" when I attempt to cd into the suggested directories to delete.

thanks in advance

Comment: I should probably add I'm reinstalling so I can get the data off of the drives.  The sata drives are striped

Comment: Out of curiosity, hardware or software (windows) raid?

Comment: no raid.. just doing jbod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the data off, don't bother repairing it.

Instead, take another drive, make it the boot drive and do a normal installation to it.  With the right disk drivers loaded you'll now be able to get at your messed-up installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to retrieve your data, use [BOOTCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), or a [bootable Linux Distro](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) to boot in, copy the data toa backup drive (Permanent or removable). Then just format the Windows Drive & install Windows.